# incorrect/overwritten margins when using vim in GNU screen

Tags: terminal, vim, gnu-screen

When ssh'd into a work server via PuTTY I'm seeing strange behavior with the left margins when using GNU screen and vim. For example, I'll open up a Python script and all indentations will be gone i.e.

```
def __init__(self):
self.name = str(self.__class__.__name__)
self.nestables = None
self.attributes = {}
```

and not

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name = str(self.__class__.__name__)
    self.nestables = None
    self.attributes = {}
```

However if I scroll down one line at a time newly appearing lines on screen will have proper indentation. I see similar behavior in htop, with the left margin getting overwritten or being indented incorrectly.

I figure there's a termcap/terminfo setting I can put in my .screenrc but everything I've tried so far has not worked.

I see this both in Debian 7 and CentOS 6.

Anyone else encountered this before?

**Edit:**
I am indenting with spaces, not tabs, and am using PuTTY from my Windows 7 workstation. I tried to reproduce the issue at a normal Windows cmd window using Cygwin/SSH and the margins are just fine, so it does appear to be PuTTY specific.

... and it turns out that I had "Implicit CR in every LF" checked by default in PuTTY and that was the culprit. Screen was a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had "Implicit CR in every LF" checked by default in PuTTY and that was the culprit. Screen was a red herring.